# iOS: How to show all lines in line graph within an small area

Tags: ios, calayer, drawrect, uibezierpath

I am showing decibel values as line graph while recording an audio in iOS. I am drawing line using `UIBezierPath` and `CALayer`.

When I stop recording, all the lines in line graph should be shown in an `UIView`. It should be like miniature of line graph while recording.

Please give suggestions.

Comment: Trying to set the layer's transform like `layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1)`